# Efficient way to subtract each vector element from matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, bsxfun

I have a function `f` which should give me a matrix where `x` is subtracted element wise from `m`

```
m = ones(4);
f = @(x) m-x;
```

when I call this function with

```
f(5)
```

everything works fine.

But how can I call this function with a vector

```
f([5,7])
```

so I get

```
-4    -4    -4    -4
-4    -4    -4    -4
-4    -4    -4    -4
-4    -4    -4    -4
```

and

```
-6    -6    -6    -6
-6    -6    -6    -6
-6    -6    -6    -6
-6    -6    -6    -6
```

in something like a 3-dimensional matrix.

If possible I'm searching for the most efficient way to do this, so I do not want to use loops.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define a function for that. Just shift the vector to the third dimension and use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
m = ones(4);
v = [5 7];
bsxfun(@minus, m, shiftdim(v(:),-2))
```

Comment: Makin' it look easy. I added a variation with `permute` for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Luis Mendo's accepted answer, you can use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to rearrange the dimensions of the vector if that is more intuitive to you than `shiftdim`:

```
v = [5 7];
bsxfun(@minus, m, permute(v,[3 1 2])) % 4x4x1 @minus 1x1x2 => 4x4x2
```

With `bsxfun`, it is all about aligning the non-singleton dimensions. Note that when doing a negative (right) effective shift, you can also use `reshape` like `reshape(v,[1,1,size(v)])` to shift from 1x2 to 1x1x1x2.

Comment: ...and that's my contribution for the weekend!

Comment: I bet it won't be your last this weekend!